# Query the usage of third party repository rules

Tags: bazel

It has always been a pain in the ass to manage third party dependencies. In our monolith repo, there are over 70 third party repos introduced with repository rules (eg. `go_repository`, `git_repository`, etc.)

Some repos are added as transitive dependencies.  After upgrading some of the direct third party dependencies, some of the transitive dependencies became dangling links.

I've already tried the following:

```
$ bazel query 'somepath(//...,@REPO_NAME_IN_QUESTION//...)'
```

Which runs extremely slow, and I ended up with a quick grep in all build files -- as the repo rules are always started with "@".

I'm wondering if there is an easy way to query the dependency graph of all rules in external repositories.

Answer (score 1):

you can try and check the performance of `rdeps`
I would recommend splitting the queries for different sections of the monolith 
e.g.:

`bazel query 'rdeps(//sub-repo/..., @external_workspace//...)'`